# Issue with AWK with handling % in data

Tags: awk

I am running into issues when handling data that contains "% F" in a file and performing awk on it.

I am trying to add two fields ($variables in shell - but hardcoded below for simplicity) to the end of each line in the file.

When awk encounters "200% F" in the data, it gives the error given below.

I can replace % with sed and replace it back later. Is there a more elegant way/workaround?

Test data given below.

**Input**

```
$ cat test1.out
a|b |c
e|200% F|f
```

**Desired output**

```
$ cat res1.out
a|b|c|123|test1.out
e|200% F|f|123|test1.out
```

**Command**

```
awk -v dlm="|" -v var1="123" -v var2="test1.out" '{printf ($0 dlm var1 dlm var2 "\n")}' test1.out > res1.out
```

**Actual Result (error)**

```
$ awk -v dlm="|" -v var1="123" -v var2="test1.out" '{printf ($0 dlm var1 dlm var2 "\n")}' test1.out > res1.out
awk: (FILENAME=test1.out FNR=2) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `e|200% F|f|123|test1.out
'
               ^ ran out for this one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `printf` here, use `print`:

```
awk -v OFS="|" -v var1="123" -v var2="test1.out" '{print $0,var1,var2}' test.out
```

You see that through the use of the `OFS` variable the `dlm` variable isn't required any more and `print` is using `|`.

---

About `printf`, whenever you want to use `printf` keep it's signature in mind:

```
printf format_string [, arg1[, arg2[,...argN ]]]
```

That means the first argument will be parsed as a format string. Since `%` has a special meaning in the format string, it will be expanded. That leads to your error.

The correct usage is like this:

```
printf "%s%s%s\n", var1, dlm, var2
```

or this:

```
printf "%s|%s\n", var1, var2
```

or even with some amount of static text like this:

```
printf "This is the output: %s|%s\n", var1, var2
```

But **not** like this:

```
printf var1, var2, "\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.

With the above solution, what if I want to add "|" at the end of the line?

Comment: You may use `{print $0,var1,var2,""}`. That would add an empty additional field which makes `print` output the delimiter at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Never use `printf $0`, always `printf "%s", $0` instead so your code doesn't fail if/when your input contains printf formatting characters. Ditto when using any other input values too.